# Linear regression: Cost function working independently, but not within a scipy.optimize function

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

I am implementing regularised linear regression. The data can be found here: https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=506A31CDF6E4A865&id=506A31CDF6E4A865%21107&parId=root&o=OneUp

My code is below:

```
import numpy as np 
import scipy.optimize as optimize
from scipy.io import loadmat

data = loadmat('ex5data1.mat')
X = data['X']
X = np.insert(X, 0, 1, axis=1)
y = data['y']
theta = np.ones((2, 1))

def cost_function(theta, X, y, reg_param):
    theta = np.matrix(theta)
    X = np.matrix(X)
    y = np.matrix(y)
    m = y.shape[0]
    h = X * theta
    error = np.power((h - y), 2)
    error = np.sum(error)
    term = error / (2*m)
    reg = (reg_param * np.sum(np.power(theta[1:, :], 2))) / (2*m)

    return term + reg

print "Cost function: \n %s" % (cost_function(theta, X, y, 1))

def cost_function_gradient(theta, X, y, reg_param):
    theta = np.matrix(theta)
    X = np.matrix(X)
    y = np.matrix(y)
    m = y.shape[0]

    grad = np.zeros((len(X[0]) + 1, 1))
    reg = np.multiply(theta[1:, :], reg_param/m)

    for j in xrange(len(X[0])):
        term = np.multiply((X * theta) - y, X[:, j + 1])
        term = np.sum(term) / m
        grad[j + 1, 0] = term + reg

    grad[0, 0] = np.sum(np.multiply((X*theta - y), X[:, 0])) / m

    return grad

print "Cost function gradient: \n %s" % (cost_function_gradient(theta, X, y, 1))

reg_param = 1
opt = optimize.fmin_cg(cost_function, theta, args=(X, y, reg_param), maxiter=200)
```

**My problem**

Before I start trying to optimise the parameters to minimise the cost function, the cost_function() and cost_function_gradient() functions work fine, outputting the correct result. However, then I start optimising the parameters, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex5.py", line 49, in <module>
    opt = optimize.fmin_cg(cost_function, theta, args=(X, y, reg_param), maxiter=200)
  File "/Users/Olly/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 1177, in fmin_cg
    res = _minimize_cg(f, x0, args, fprime, callback=callback, **opts)
  File "/Users/Olly/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 1228, in _minimize_cg
    gfk = myfprime(x0)
  File "/Users/Olly/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 292, in function_wrapper
    return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
  File "/Users/Olly/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 688, in approx_fprime
    return _approx_fprime_helper(xk, f, epsilon, args=args)
  File "/Users/Olly/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 622, in _approx_fprime_helper
    f0 = f(*((xk,) + args))
  File "/Users/Olly/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py", line 292, in function_wrapper
    return function(*(wrapper_args + args))
  File "ex5.py", line 17, in cost_function
    h = X * theta
  File "/Users/Olly/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py", line 309, in __mul__
    return N.dot(self, asmatrix(other))
ValueError: shapes (12,2) and (1,2) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```

So it seems that when the fmin_cg() function starts, the dimensions of X and theta are changed/used differently. I attempted to change X, y and theta to matrices before applying fmin_cg() but this didn't change anything.

Could someone please explain why this is working outside of the fmin_cg() function but not within it?

How could I change my code to make this work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start with ```np.ones((2, 1)) -> np.ones(2)```

Comment: @sascha could you explain what that does/why to do it?

Comment: It throws up the same error

Comment: Your init has 2 dims. 1 dim is expected. Of course you might need to change the remaining code to reflect this. And never show a trimmed error-message here. Put the whole error in your question. Also: it's not reproducible. Create synthetic-data or upload that file.

Comment: @sascha Thanks for the advice, I've done both now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in defining the parameters array as

```
theta = np.ones((2, 1))
```

This manifests itself in the error:

```
ValueError: shapes (12,2) and (1,2) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```

which describes a mismatch in the dimensions of the theta array and the X array. This can be remedied by defining theta like so:

```
theta = np.ones(2)
```

This creates the exact same thing as theta((2, 1)), except it is reshaped. The only difference that needs to be made to the code above now is in taking the transpose of all thetas in their multiplications to make sure that the matrix multiplications are legal. Here is the fully working code:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import scipy.optimize as optimize 
from scipy.io import loadmat

data = loadmat('ex5data1.mat')
x = data['X']
X = data['X']
X = np.insert(X, 0, 1, axis=1)
y = data['y']
theta = np.ones(2)

def cost_function(theta, X, y, reg_param):
    theta = np.matrix(theta)
    X = np.matrix(X)
    y = np.matrix(y)
    m = float(y.shape[0])
    h = X * theta.T
    error = np.power((h - y), 2)
    error = np.sum(error)
    term = error / (2*m)
    reg = (reg_param * np.sum(np.power(theta[1:, :], 2))) / (2*m)

return term + reg

print "Cost function: \n %s" % (cost_function(theta, X, y, 1))

def cost_function_gradient(theta, X, y, reg_param):
    theta = np.matrix(theta)
    X = np.matrix(X)
    y = np.matrix(y)
    m = float(y.shape[0])

    grad = np.zeros((len(X[0]) + 1, 1))
    reg = np.multiply(theta.T[1:, :], reg_param/m)

    for j in xrange(len(X[0])):
        term = np.multiply((X * theta.T) - y, X[:, j + 1])
        term = np.sum(term) / m
        grad[j + 1, 0] = term + reg

    grad[0, 0] = np.sum(np.multiply((X*theta.T - y), X[:, 0])) / m

    return grad

print "Cost function gradient: \n %s" % (cost_function_gradient(theta, X, y, 1))

reg_param = 0
opt = optimize.fmin_cg(cost_function, theta, args=(X, y, reg_param), maxiter=200)
```